# Trouble with PHP date() - remaining days in month

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I am trying to calculate the remaining days in a month from any given day. I have the following code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo $timestamp = date('Y-m-d');
echo " - ";
echo $daysInMonth = (int)date('t', $timestamp);
echo " - ";
echo $thisDayInMonth = (int)date('j', $timestamp);
echo " - ";
echo $daysRemaining = $daysInMonth - $thisDayInMonth;
?>
```

The output is:
2016-12-14 - 31 - 1 - 30

I have also tried with date('d', $timestamp), but it still returns 1 for the present day even though it should be 14. Why am I getting 1 for the present day? Thanks.

My PHP version is 5.4.45.

Comment: try to do `$timestamp = time()` instead of `$timestamp = date('Y-m-d')`

Comment: Use `DateTime` instead. https://3v4l.org/bLOO7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to the timestamp variable since date function needs second parameter as integer value. But when you supply formatted date, it is considered string.

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo $timestamp = date('Y-m-d');
echo " - ";
echo $daysInMonth = (int)date('t', strtotime($timestamp));
echo " - ";
echo $thisDayInMonth = (int)date('j', strtotime($timestamp));
echo " - ";
echo $daysRemaining = $daysInMonth - $thisDayInMonth;
```

Output:

```
2016-12-14 - 31 - 14 - 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/datetime) makes this much simpler:-

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$daysRemaining = (int)$now->format('t') - (int)$now->format('d');
```

[See it working](https://3v4l.org/aCb9O).